# Why is it not giving me distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems that without the inner join, it gives me the distinct values but with it, its displaying all of them. Why isn't it giving me distinct values?

Hers my code:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.manager_account_id 
  , first_name
  , last_name
  , m.active
  , m.user_name
  , d.department_name
FROM tbl_Manager_Accounts m
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Manager_App_Link mal ON m.manager_account_id = mal.manager_account_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Application a ON a.application_id = mal.application_id
INNER JOIN tbl_Department d on a.department_id=d.department_id
WHERE a.department_id = @department_id and m.user_name not like '%admin%'
OR m.department_id = @department_id and m.user_name not like '%admin%'
ORDER BY last_name
```

My manager_id's are coming out as such:

383
381
381
381
2877
382
2876
435
435
435
435
435
435

Comment: Only select m.manager_account_id

Comment: DISTINCT applies to the whole column list, not just first column.

Comment: I need to display all of the other columns too though. The other columns come up, I just didn't list it in my post because of the security of the data. @BrankoDimitrijevic

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate only one row per `ManagerId` and still display all the other fields you want.... What is the computer to do when there are multiple rows in the join table for the same `ManagerID` ??  Should it guess?

If you need to display data from another table where there are multiple rows (with different values) in those extra fields, then you need to specify which value to extract. You can use a aggregate function like `Min` or `Max` with a `group By`  as in:

```
SELECT m.manager_account_id,
    first_name firstName, last_name last_name
    Min(m.active) Active,
    Min(m.user_name) username,
    Min(d.department_name) DeptName
FROM tbl_Manager_Accounts m
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Manager_App_Link mal 
        ON m.manager_account_id = mal.manager_account_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Application a 
        ON a.application_id = mal.application_id
    JOIN tbl_Department d 
        on a.department_id=d.department_id
WHERE a.department_id = @department_id and m.user_name not like '%admin%'
    OR m.department_id = @department_id and m.user_name not like '%admin%'
Group By m.manager_account_id, first_name, last_name
ORDER BY last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Only select m.manager_account_id should solve your issue.

**Corrected query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    m.manager_account_id 
FROM tbl_Manager_Accounts m
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Manager_App_Link mal ON m.manager_account_id = mal.manager_account_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Application a ON a.application_id = mal.application_id
INNER JOIN tbl_Department d on a.department_id=d.department_id
WHERE a.department_id = @department_id and m.user_name not like '%admin%'
OR m.department_id = @department_id and m.user_name not like '%admin%'
ORDER BY last_name
```

Comment: I need to display all of the other columns too though. The other columns come up, I just didn't list it in my post because of the security of the data. @fabigler